# Weird behavior of std::replace_copy used with std::string

Tags: c++, string, stl

i have this simple code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s = "1,0";
    string result;

    //result.resize(s.length());
    replace_copy(s.begin(), s.end(), result.begin(), ',', '.');

    cout << '"' << result         << '"' << endl;
    cout << '"' << result.c_str() << '"' << endl;
    cout << result.length() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Console output of this program with `result.resize` line uncommented is:

```
"1.0"
"1.0"
3
```

-thats Ok, but when line with `result.resize` is commented-out, output is :

```
""
"1.0"
0
```

-this can leads into weird errors because `result != result.c_str()` !!!

Can this behavior of `replace_copy` (and posibly also similar templates) may be considered as error in standard library? I cannot find anything relevant to this subject. Thanks.

Compiler: mingw32-g++ 4.7.1

Answer (score 5):

What did you expect?

**Without the `resize`, there is no space in your string for the new characters.**

Trying to copy into that space regardless will definitely result in "weird" [read: *undefined*] behaviour. You're mangling your memory.

`replace_copy` copies to a target range, which is not the same as inserting new elements into a target container. The range has to already exist…

… unless you use a `back_inserter`, which functions as a sort of fake range, that *actually* performs insertion under the hood:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s = "1,0";
    string result;

    //result.resize(s.length());   // Look, ma! No hands!
    replace_copy(
        s.begin(), s.end(),
        std::back_inserter<std::string>(result),
        ',', '.'
    );

    cout << '"' << result         << '"' << endl;
    cout << '"' << result.c_str() << '"' << endl;
    cout << result.length() << endl;
}

// "1.0"
// "1.0"
// 3
```

### [Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a331dd2371249221)

<sup>**Warning!** Getting the right output in that live demo does not *prove* anything, as undefined behaviour can occasionally "appear to work". However, I have 96k rep and you can trust me. ;)</sup>

Comment: +1 for mentioning `back_inserter`.  That was one of the first things that came to mind.

Comment: About my expectations on well designed library which STL is: Why not replace_copy in this case simply dont leave destination untouched (Or at least generate assert) and instead violates invariants of string internals? For this reason, I asked if it can be considered an error in standard library.

Comment: @user3123061: It is not an error in the standard library, but an error in your usage of it. The invariants are to be maintained _by you_, not by forcing potentially expensive runtime checks that not everybody will want. More practically, it is not feasible to detect the _length_ or the _validity_ of a range from a single iterator.

Answer (score 1):

When you used statement

```
result.resize(s.length());
```

you created and initialized (more precisely assigned) the string with three elements with values '\0'. When this statement was not used the string had no relements and the behaviour of the program was undefined.In fact the code with uncommented line is equivalent to the following:

```
string s = "1,0";
string result( s.length(), '\0' );

replace_copy(s.begin(), s.end(), result.begin(), ',', '.');
```

If to write as it was with the commented statement then you should use iterator adapter `std::back_insert_iterator`For example

```
replace_copy(s.begin(), s.end(), std::back_inserter( result ), ',', '.');
```